# tidyr spread sorting inconsistencies

Tags: r, key-value, tidyr, spread

Ive noticed `tidyr(0.4.0)` sorts value columns when using `spread`, where as `tidyr(0.3.1)` returns the value columns in the order they were prior to a `gather`.

**Reproducible example 1:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# tidyr 0.3.1

dat<-data.frame(name=rep(c("A","B"),5),sam.id=rep(c(1,2),5),
      frac=sample(c(0.05,0.1,0.2),10,replace=TRUE),
      Aspecies=rnorm(10),Bspecies=rnorm(10),Zspecies=rnorm(10))
```

I aggregate the species values by both `sam.id` and `frac`(*the proportion of the sample measured*) i.e a multiple `gather`.

```
dt.agg.0.3.1 <- gather(dat,key,value,-name,-sam.id) %>% 
                group_by(name,key) %>% 
                summarise(Total=sum(value)) %>% spread(key,Total) %>%
                mutate(all=rowSums(.[,3:5]))
```

The last part of the pipe computes a simple total of all species using `mutate`. So that:

```
head(dt.agg.0.3.1)

Source: local data frame [2 x 6]

name  frac  Aspecies    Bspecies  Zspecies       all
(fctr) (dbl)     (dbl)       (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1      A  0.85 -2.675137 -0.03287276  1.016791 -1.858010
2      B  0.40  4.194904  1.50561762 -2.738543  6.100522
```

**Reproducible example 2:**

```
library(tidyr)
# 0.4.0

dt.agg.0.4.0 <- gather(dat,key,value,-name,-sam.id) %>%
                group_by(name,key) %>% 
                summarise(Total=sum(value)) %>% spread(key,Total)

head(dt.agg.0.4.0)

Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
Groups: name [2]

name  Aspecies    Bspecies  frac  Zspecies
(fctr)     (dbl)       (dbl) (dbl)     (dbl)
1      A -2.675137 -0.03287276  0.85  1.016791
2      B  4.194904  1.50561762  0.40 -2.738543
```

One can see how the ordering of the value columns has been changed (alphabetically), which makes additional data-pipeline steps using `mutate` for example troublesome.

```
dt.agg.0.4.0.mutated <- gather(dat,key,value,-name,-sam.id) %>%
                        group_by(name,key) %>% summarise(Total=sum(value)) %>%
                        spread(key,Total) %>% mutate(all=rowSums(.[,2:5]))
```

Throws the error;

```
Error: incompatible size (2), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1
```

Is there a way for `tidyr(0.4.0)` to `spread` back out in the order of the `gather`?

Or will have to `gather` (and `summarise`) twice -- once for each key-value pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ungroup` after the `spread` and `grep` the columns that needs to used for `rowSums` (`tidyr_0.4.0`).

```
gather(dat, key, value, -name, sam.id) %>% 
           group_by(name, key) %>% 
           summarise(Total=sum(value)) %>%
           spread(key, Total) %>%
           ungroup() %>%
           mutate(all= rowSums(.[grep('species', names(.))]))
#     name Aspecies   Bspecies  frac sam.id Zspecies      all
#   (fctr)    (dbl)      (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)
#1      A 5.795958 -0.4769954   0.4      5 3.965114 9.284077
#2      B 2.475395 -1.4858969   0.5     10 1.045175 2.034674
```

If we need to get the order of the columns as that occurs in the 'key' column, then we may need to convert the 'key' to `factor` class with `levels` specified.  In this case, we can use the position index in `rowSums`.

```
gather(dat,key,value,-name,-sam.id) %>% 
      mutate(key= factor(key, levels=unique(key))) %>% 
      group_by(name, key) %>%
      summarise(Total = sum(value)) %>% 
      spread(key, Total) %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      mutate(all = rowSums(.[3:5]))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 6]

#    name  frac Aspecies   Bspecies Zspecies      all
#  (fctr) (dbl)    (dbl)      (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)
#1      A   0.4 5.795958 -0.4769954 3.965114 9.284077
#2      B   0.5 2.475395 -1.4858969 1.045175 2.034674
```

---

If we look at the `str` after the `spread` step i.e.

```
res <- gather(dat, key, value, -name, sam.id) %>% 
                   group_by(name, key) %>% 
                   summarise(Total=sum(value)) %>% 
                   spread(key, Total)

str(res)
#Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  6 variables:
#...
```

One of the `class` is 'grouped_df', which somehow creates the problem.

```
str(res %>% ungroup)  
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       2 obs. of  6 variables:
```

NOTE: The values are different from the OP's post as no `set.seed` was specified.

Comment: great! I'll use `mutate(key= factor(key, levels=unique(key)))` as the actual species names vary but are rather arranged in sequential columns...

Comment: @kleanBean The `unique(key)` will order the elements in the `key` as it appears in the column.  If you need a custom order, then specify the levels as it is needed.  i.e. `levels = c('frac', 'Aspecies', 'Somethingelse'...`  Regarding the difference in both versions, this may be a bug..

Comment: Now there is a parameter for `gather()` `factor_key=T` which preserves the original order too.